# Could any one give explanation for this Multi-Function loop with "ZIP"?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
try:
    url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[(@class = 'ipc-title ipc-title--base ipc-title--title ipc-title-link-no-icon ipc-title--on-textPrimary sc-43986a27-9 gaoUku cli-title')]/a/h3")
    year = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[(@class = 'sc-43986a27-8 jHYIIK cli-title-metadata-item')][1]")
    
    for i,j in zip(title,year):
        print(i.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
        print(j.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Just wanted to know is there any other way that i can use multiple function in a forloop without using ZIP comman.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure what you mean by multiple function

Comment: in the above code i am using two variable title and year together and i am printing the value simultaneously. for past 30 min i had a problem printing the same value in that order and then i came accross ZIP command to use it together.

Comment: i just wanted to know can i do it without using ZIP command.

Comment: The `zip` command is pairing the found `title` with the found `year` so that they can be quickly iterated over at the same time.  A better code example may call these variables `titles` and `years` to suggest that they're a listing of each.  If you need to pair more items, you may add them to the zip constructor and still access them by index.  Warning, the `zip` function will only return the smallest of those lists.   See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/

If you don't need to iterate over two or more lists at the same time like the example, you can omit the `zip` portion.

Comment: Thank you. i was confused with nesting and wasted 30 min then came accross ZIP that helped in last. i will go through  geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python for more detail as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over both using index

```
for i in range(len(title)):
    print(title[i].get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    print(year[i].get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

however I think you should find a common parent and use it to locate the elements you are looking for

```
items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ipc-metadata-list-summary-item__c')

for item in items:
    print(item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'ipc-title__text').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print(item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cli-title-metadata-item').get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Output

```
1. The Shawshank Redemption
1994
2. The Godfather
1972
3. The Dark Knight
2008
4. The Godfather Part II
1974
5. 12 Angry Men
1957
...
```

Comment: Thank you. it is something new for me and also i like this approach as by using this format i can practice implementing it on multiple large Data set.